# How can I make it so only one object in a group is visible at a time?

Tags: groups, outliner

I want it so that if I make an object in a group visible, it automatically makes the others invisible.

Comment: What is your desired result? Animation? Just UI interaction? Organizing scene while modelling? To hide all the others object in the scene press Shift+H with one selected. Further info would be required for more detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can't be accomplished in current Blender versions through standard UI/ Tools. Something like this has yet to be written for Blender.

(Edited for being to vague.)

Comment: So generally your answer is "maybe sometime this will be possible but I don't know if it is now"

Comment: No, my answer is that it is impossible with blender "as is" in the current state.  Then I just point out that there might be a solution in the future. Would you prefer me to say: No, not possible! And nothing else? Because that's not quite true.

Comment: OK, I see your point. Will edit point 2 and 3 out of the answer.

Comment: Is the script window a standard interface tool?